# How to pass message from servlet to jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I want to pass a status parameter from servlet to jsp. I am sending it through

```
response.sendRedirect("newpage.jsp?status=yes");
```

If `status = yes` then show success message in `<div>` and then set **status** to `null`. But when the `newpage.jsp` loads at the first time the value of **status** is `null` and it gives **null pointer exception**.

Same thing happens with session also.

```
<% 
   String status = request.getParameter("status");
   System.out.println("Check Successful of Status"+status);
   if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
   System.out.println("Check Successful of Status");
%>

<div style="color: green;" align="center">Selected tenant approved successfully</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> window.location.href = window.location.href.split("?")[0]; </script>

<%
   request.setAttribute("status1", null); 
%>
```

Comment: if you got your answer just mark has resolve by picking a answer by checking it so people know that it been answering.

Comment: The question is not clear. You're already using `response.sendRedirect("newpage.jsp?status=yes");` so what are you asking for exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Servlet you can use

```
request.setAttribute("status","yes")
```

in jsp, you can retrieve using

```
request.getAttribute("status");
```

Yes, I missed the point

for above u need to use

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("somefile.jsp");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

If u want to use `response.sendRedirect("somefile.jsp")`,

u can set the variable in session as

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

session.setAttribute("status","yes")
```

and get it back as

`session.getAttribute("status")`.

Once used, u can remove it as

```
session.removeAttribute("status")
```

Comment: Yes but when first time the page will load the value of status would be null... and it will give null pointer exception. So how to avoid null pointer exception

Comment: if(request.getAttribute("status")!=null) { //ur code }

Comment: No you can't, not unless you also use a dispatcher and forward.  You can't use request.setAttribute() with response.sendRedirect()!

Answer (score 1):

```
request.setAttribute("status1", yourstatus); 
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("yourpageyouwanttosend.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

your view `<%= request.getAttribute("status1") %>`

Comment: Yes but when first time the page will load the value of status would be null... and it will give null pointer exception. So how to avoid null pointer exception.

Comment: request.setAttribute("status1", null); status already null you have to specific it with some value

Answer (score 0):

You are using `status` as parameter name and you are comparing `status1` in your JSP

```
    if (status1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
```

---

Note:

placing javacode on jsp is not good thing, switch to [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Yes but when first time the page will load the value of status would be null... and it will give null pointer exception. So how to avoid null pointer exception